# Algorithms to optimize over an interval union a singleton.

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming

Sorry for the simple question, but my Google skills were not enough. I have a large optimization problem and I would like to add constraints of the following kind:

$$ x \in \{ 0 \} \cup [c, \infty) $$

with $c > 0$ a constant. Do these optimization problems have a name? Are there any algorithms to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can't you just solve it for the constraint $x=0$ and then for the constraint $x\in [c, \infty)$ and take the maximum/minimum of the two results?

Comment: @FelixB. sadly, no. My question was general, I'm sorry. To be specific, several variables $x_i$ have their own constraint, with their own constant $c_i$. Added to that, I have constraints of the type $\sum_i x_i = B$, with $B > 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are called *semicontinuous* variables.  Because $x_i$ has an implied finite upper bound of $B$, you can model this situation by introducing a binary variable $y_i$ and linear constraints:
$$c_i y_i \le x_i \le B y_i$$
If $y=0$ then $x_i=0$. If $y=1$ then $c_i \le x_i \le B$.